# How to send an email with test report in Cypress

Tags: email, cypress, nodemailer, test-reporting

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Create a simple test report with only names of tests and statuses (Fail/Pass)
2. Send this report as basic HTML via email.

To achieve that, I need:

1. A basic reporter instead of the default
2. Library, which can send an email. I have already tried `nodemailer`. However, it is not sending any email when I am connecting it with Cypress solution. I have tried different mailbox accounts (`nodemailer.createTestAccount()`, one from my company, and one from  SendGrid), and this is not working (I am not receiving any emails)

Regarding point 2, here is a sample of code I used. This is a code in index.js file - I need to send it after all tests:

```
after(() => {

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

var options = {
  auth: {
    api_user: 'sendgrid_USER',
    api_key: 'sendgrid_APIKEY'
  }
}

var client = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

var email = {
    from: 'FROM_MAIL.PL',
    to: 'TO_MAIL.PL',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Hello world',
  html: '<b>Hello world</b>'
};

client.sendMail(email, function(err, info){
    if (err ){
      console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Can you please [edit] the question and add any error messages or bounce reasons?

Comment: @Robert I will update, however, the problem is that t is not sending any emails. I have currently no idea why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) is a module for Node.js, so you will need to run it in a Cypress task.

Add this to your **/cypress/plugins/index.js** file

```js
const sendAnEmail = (message) => {

  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  const sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');
  const options = {
    auth: {
      api_user: 'sendgrid_USER',
      api_key: 'sendgrid_APIKEY'
    }
  }
  const client = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

  const email = {
    from: 'FROM_MAIL.PL',
    to: 'TO_MAIL.PL',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: message,
    html: '<b>Hello world</b>'
  };
  client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
    return err? err.message : 'Message sent: ' + info.response;
  });
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    sendMail (message) {
      return sendAnEmail(message);
    }
  })
}
```

then in the test (or in **/cypress/support/index.js** for all tests)

```js
after(() => {
  cy.task('sendMail', 'This will be output to email address')
    .then(result => console.log(result));
})
```

This is a basic refactor of the example [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Usage), you can adjust things to suit your requirements.

Comment: What I wanted to do is to send this email from Index.js, as this needs to be done after ALL tests (`after` section). Can I also run this task there? So both your examples will be in index.js

Comment: Yes you can run a task within an `after()` hook in **/cypress/support/index.js** (not to be confused with **/cypress/plugins/index.js** where the task is defined).

Comment: thanks! This makes it all clear now. Sending emails is working great. I just need to find out how to prepare a plain Test report

Comment: I saw an error cy.task('sendMail') failed with the following error:
The task 'sendMail' returned undefined. You must return a value, null, or a promise that resolves to a value or null to indicate that the task was handled.

The task handler was:

sendMail (message) {
      return sendAnEmail(message);
    }
Could you please help with this?